# Meaning of "this project" in this context

Tags: phrase-meaning

> In 1482, Quasimodo was about 20 years old. Claude Frollo had turned 36. The priest was still involved in the education of his younger brother, Jehan. **But this project** had caused him bitterness. Jehan had grown up to be wild, lazy, and ignorant. He was more interested in having fun than in studying. This saddened his older brother. He threw himself even more into the study of science. As a priest, he became more learned and more severe. As a man, he became sour and gloomy.

What does "this project" mean in this passage? Does it mean "the teaching of his brother and the responsibility he had for educating him"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. "This" shows that the writer is referring to the thing mentioned immediately before. Again, later, the boy is said to be more interested in having fun than studying. The next sentence is "**This** saddened his older brother."

Answer (score 0):

"***But this project had caused him [bitterness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bitterness)***." According to the author,I assume that the priest was responsible in educating his younger brother, Jehan and ***this project*** meaning that this task or responsibility of making his younger brother study was very rough and caused an intensely unpleasant grief or regret aroused/developed on seeing that Jehan was more interested in having fun than studying.